# Load Content with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

newbie alert here!

I want to load some content of my site with ajax calls.
To be more specific i want firstly to load the page and after the page has completed loading, then i want to show some content (divs).

Could you give me some advice or turn me to any good tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: For the record, this problem is largely independent of your server-side code, so that you're using Kohana doesn't make much difference :)

Comment: @will i warned you "newbie alert here!"

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Kohana. Removing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days, most people use jQuery for their Javascript needs.

The jQuery ajax function may help you out here.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/